# Twitter search api parameters

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-rest-api

In **twitter search api**, I'm able to find new paramter **src = 'typd' or src = 'sprv'**, getting different results for each src paramter.But I'm unable to figure it out, what the term **'typd' and 'sprv' means**?
for eg:
https://twitter.com/search?q=Technology&src=typd
https://twitter.com/search?q=Technology&src=sprv

Answer (score 3):

'sprv' and 'typd' relate to [Twitter's spelling correction system](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/related-queries-and-spelling-corrections-in-search). As Leb said, 'typd' indicates results from a query that was typed-in and may be incorrect; while 'sprv' is a clear "no, I really meant this".

For example, if I type 'flayrah' into the search bar I get results for 'flayra' at URL https://twitter.com/search?q=flayrah&src=typd and the text "Showing results for flayra. Search for [flayrah](https://twitter.com/search?q=flayrah&src=sprv) instead."

Clicking the link brings me to https://twitter.com/search?q=flayrah&src=sprv with results for 'flayrah'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `sprv` means but those two links aren't giving me different results, they're the exact same.

`typd` means that you actually typed the query into the [search](https://twitter.com/search-home) yourself.

Also note that the search through the previous link and search through Rest API (per your tag) are two different things.

> The Twitter Search API is part of Twitter’s v1.1 REST API. It allows queries against the indices of recent or popular Tweets and behaves similarily to, but not exactly like the Search feature available in Twitter mobile or web clients, such as Twitter.com search.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: 'sprv' appears to be a "spelling reversion/review" as noted in my answer.